# Error: Invalid OAuth response from google.com

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine

We just started receiving this message, we changed nothing:

[image]

Comment: I also got this error for all of my firebase app, but it is now ok. It should be ok also for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is firebase error, because I was testing my ionic app and I have the same error and I have not changed anything.

Answer (score 0):

Google is reporting Authentication service disruption https://status.firebase.google.com/
https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Authentication/19001

Answer (score 0):

This was an open issue for Google:
https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Authentication/19001